# O365 API filter on complex types

Tags: odata, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

What is the query to get emails received from a specific sender email address?

I have tried filtering on the "Address" property of the "From" property, which is a "Recipient" complex type according to O365 Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model namespace.

OData filtering on complex types goes something like this

```
/Me/Inbox/Messages?$filter=From/Address eq 'email@email.com'
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "The property 'Address' is invalid.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "The property 'Address' is invalid.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.InvalidPropertyException",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.SchemaExtensions.ResolveProperty(Schema schema, String propertyName)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EwsFilterConverter.GetPropertyProvider(QueryNode queryNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EwsFilterConverter.ConvertFilterNode(QueryNode queryNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EwsQueryAdapter.GetRestriction()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.MessageProvider.Find(String parentFolderId, MessageQueryAdapter queryAdapter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.FindMessagesCommand.InternalExecute()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.Execute()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataTask.Execute(TimeSpan queueAndDelayTime, TimeSpan totalTime)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error that property of complex type is invalid.

It seems that exchange service does not support complex type filtering.

You can try getting all the Messages to local storage and doing filtering.

Comment: Do you know if complex type filtering support is planned for future updates?

Comment: No idea about that. Maybe you can contact the exchange team.

Answer (score 0):

Email address is a complex type however it is listed as filterable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) which means the following should work...

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=From/EmailAddress/Address eq 'email@email.com'

However, I'm having trouble with this, it seems to be simply returning blank values whereas the following works...

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=From/EmailAddress/Name eq 'Joe Bloggs'

So, there could be a fault with the API or the email address might need to be formatted differently.